# My code/local/ is being overidden, how do I find out where!

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi I basically have a code/local/ of a core file I edited.

/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/block/sales/order/Grid.php

This was to add a "Company" column to the order grid.

Since updating to 1.9.2.2 and updating a few plugins around the site this has stopped working.

I am guessing another plugin is over riding my function or extending the class elsewhere?

I have had a look in the folders in my code/local/ but can't seem to find anything.

Is there a debug tool I can use in the backend of magento or a way of finding out what it going over my codes head?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use the great magerun tool.

You can get the list of rewrites with this command:

https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun#rewrite-list

Comment: Thank you for sharing this tool! I can see two plugins are extending the class "Ext4mage_Orders2csv_Block_Sales_Order_Grid, AuIt_Pdf_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid" however as I have my copy of Grid.php in "local" how are they over-riding it when they are in community? Also both these grid files only have one function in "_prepareMassaction" which isnt the function I am editing in my Grid.php :S

Comment: My suggestion is to disable those two rewrites and move the changes they implement into a module of yours where you can also add the modification you've implemented in your local folder. Magento does not support multiple rewrites for the same class.

Comment: So what am I to do if a plugin overwrites a class only for one particular function and I need to overwrite the same class to edit a different function?